# nvd3 , where is code for nv.models?

Tags: d3.js, legend, nvd3.js

I creating an nvd3 chart.

I have been looking through the code and it has references to nv.models.axis()

or nv.models.legend()

Do you know where I can find the code for these things?

Thanks

Comment: The respective files in the [repository](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/tree/master/src/models).

Comment: You can find them here: https://github.com/novus/nvd3/tree/master/src/models

Comment: ok Thanks! I have one follow up question for you guys, do you know if it is possible to move the position of the legend?

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139329/vertically-align-nvd3-legend)

Comment: Thanks again! and sorry I have another question that is probably obvious to you. In my code , the line to change the position is     g.select('.nv-legendWrap')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(50,400)'). do you know what is happening here? where is .nv-legendwrap defined? and what does g.select do?

Comment: If you search for "nv-legendWrap" in the [nvd3 source code](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/nv.d3.js), you can see that it is added to the chart by nvd3 itself as part of the skeleton. 

What `g.select('.nv-legendWrap').attr...` does is find anything under the `g` object that has a class name of `nv-legendWrap`, apply the attribute `transform` with the value of `translate...` to it.

I suggest you check out this free ebook on D3.js - [Interactive Data Visualization for the Web](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help Quinn, do you know if there is a straightforward way of adding a second axis on nvd3?